# ScriptIgnore atribute do not work in Linq to SQL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql, serialization

I am getting error on one of the fields(Linq to SQL model) while serializing with JavaScriptSerializer.

```
Unhandled: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'Entity.ProductType'.
```

I decided to put ScriptIgnore attribute to ignore ProductType field serialization.

```
   public interface IProduct
    {
        [ScriptIgnore]
        ProductType ProductType { get; set; }

    }

    [MetadataType(typeof(IProduct))]
    public partial class Product : IProduct
    {   
    }
```

Unfortunately I am still get the error. Why ScriptIgnore do not work?

Comment: What about the other fields? Are you sure that only this Field can cause Circular references?

Comment: Yes, because Exception gives field name which gives error.

Comment: Use view models. Don't pass your domain models to views.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the following reasons, in my company we decided to not serialize Linq2SQL entities directly:

1. Every time the `.dbml` is re-generated, it ignores your attributes declarations and clear them.
2. In our case, as we were serializing the Entities directly to our Views, we put some thought on it and we realized that the convinience could bring some problems.

Some of the points about the reasons:

- Direct serialization is just a convenience, so it could become a overhead if we were serializing it via network.
- `.dbml` changes, and one programmer can break another's work just because he didn't know that some property he added could bring circular problems. It's improductive.
- Depending on the case, exposing your model could be dangerous.
- It's not that bad to expose another object, just with the properties you need. Example:

  ```
  var person = personDAO.getById(123);

  return new
  {
      Code = person.Id,
      Name = person.FirstName + " " + person.LastName
  };
  ```

Again, it depends on your case. If you are serializing it to your view, I don't think is a good idea. If you are serializing it to another App, it wouldn't be a problem, so keep it in this way and avoid circular serialization.